# Qual a diferença entre o uso das constantes do enum StandardCopyOption?

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou implementando cópia de arquivos e decidi utilizar a classe [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), e uma das assinaturas do método [`copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) é receber 2 parâmetros do tipo `Path` e um terceiro do tipo `CopyOption` e é neste último que fiquei com dúvidas.

Para passar este terceiro parâmetro, utiliza-se o enum [StandardCopyOption](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html), e ele possui 3 constantes:

> ATOMIC_MOVE
>   Move the file as an atomic file system operation.
>
> COPY_ATTRIBUTES
>   Copy attributes to the new file.
>
> REPLACE_EXISTING
>   Replace an existing file if it exists.

A última eu até entendi que é sobre reescrita de arquivos, caso ele já exista no path de destino mas mesmo lendo a definição dos outros dois, me gerou algumas duvidas:

A cópia em si já não copia os atributos do arquivo de origem por padrão, já que estamos criando réplica do arquivo em outro local?

O que o `ATOMIC_MOVE` faz de diferente da cópia comum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Como as flags são usadas

Todas as flags são passadas para a implementação de cópia de arquivos específica de cada sistema operacional.

Por exemplo, no caso de sistemas baseados no UNIX, a classe [`UnixCopyFile`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixCopyFile.java) utiliza as opções para determinar se deve realizar determinadas operações adicionais.

Trecho relevante da classe `UnixCopyFile`:

```
static Flags fromMoveOptions(CopyOption... options) {
    Flags flags = new Flags();
    for (CopyOption option: options) {
        if (option == StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE) {
            flags.atomicMove = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (option == StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING) {
            flags.replaceExisting = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (option == LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS) {
            // ignore
            continue;
        }
        if (option == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported copy option");
    }

    // a move requires that all attributes be copied but only fail if
    // the basic attributes cannot be copied
    flags.copyBasicAttributes = true;
    flags.copyPosixAttributes = true;
    flags.copyNonPosixAttributes = true;
    flags.failIfUnableToCopyBasic = true;
    return flags;
}
```

## Cópia de atributos

Especificamente sobre `COPY_ATTRIBUTES`, geralmente copiar um arquivo significa criar um novo no local de destino e copiar o conteúdo.

Atributos do arquivo como data de último acesso, data de modificação e permissões geralmente recebem os valores padrão de um arquivo novo.

Portanto, tal flag faz com que o novo arquivo recebe os mesmos valores nesses atributos. Note que nem sempre é isto que queremos. Copiar poucas vezes tem o sentido completo de replicar na prática.

Trecho relevante da classe `UnixCopyFile`:

```
// copy owner/permissions
if (flags.copyPosixAttributes) {
    try {
        fchown(fo, attrs.uid(), attrs.gid());
        fchmod(fo, attrs.mode());
    } catch (UnixException x) {
        if (flags.failIfUnableToCopyPosix)
            x.rethrowAsIOException(target);
    }
}
// copy non POSIX attributes (depends on file system)
if (flags.copyNonPosixAttributes) {
    source.getFileSystem().copyNonPosixAttributes(fi, fo);
}
// copy time attributes
if (flags.copyBasicAttributes) {
    try {
        futimes(fo,
                attrs.lastAccessTime().to(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS),
                attrs.lastModifiedTime().to(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS));
    } catch (UnixException x) {
        if (flags.failIfUnableToCopyBasic)
            x.rethrowAsIOException(target);
    }
}
```

## Operações atômicas

A flag `ATOMIC_MOVE` na verdade não se aplica nas operações de cópia, apesar do nome do `enum`, mas ao mover um arquivo.

No caso de sistemas baseados no UNIX, o Java usa o comando [`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) para mudar o arquivo do caminho de origem para o caminho de destino, pois este comando é atômico.

Além disso, o código Java não realiza outras operações adicionais, tal como verificar se o arquivo de destino existe, pois isto tornaria o processo sujeito a condições de corrida, isto é, não atômico.

Trecho relevante da classe `UnixCopyFile`:

```
// handle atomic rename case
if (flags.atomicMove) {
    try {
        rename(source, target);
    } catch (UnixException x) {
        if (x.errno() == EXDEV) {
            throw new AtomicMoveNotSupportedException(
                source.getPathForExecptionMessage(),
                target.getPathForExecptionMessage(),
                x.errorString());
        }
        x.rethrowAsIOException(source, target);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Então operações de cópia não são atômicas? Isso explica alguns problemas que tive, como cópias incompletas e as vezes cópias com dados corrompidos.

Comment: @diegofm É um problema comum. Do ponto de vista de um programa *single-threaded*, as operações em disco são atômicas. Porém, outros processos ou *threads* conseguem enxergar um arquivo que acabou de ser criado enquanto você ainda está começando a gravar os dados nele.

Comment: Se você trabalha com integração de arquivos, onde um programa gera o arquivo e outro programa consome, vejo duas opções: ou você faz com que o programa de origem avise o programa de destino quando o arquivo estiver completo, ou, se usa monitoramento de diretórios, grave o conteúdo num arquivo temporário e, somente ao terminar, mova o arquivo para o diretório onde ele será lido.